# multi-line text-input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to create a multi-line text-input field? I need something that works as a textarea (with line-wrap) but without being able to 'return' to the next line. Or should i create a textarea and disable the enter-button?

Comment: you gave the answer in your question... use a textarea.

Comment: Why not just use a textarea and then remove then remove the line breaks on the server?  Sounds like a frustrating interface, "Why can't I hit enter?!"

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it without javascript. Check the second demo textarea in [this tutorial](http://www.web-wise-wizard.com/html-tutorials/html-form-forms-textarea-wrap.html), it does what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead with the last option, I think it's the better path.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple constraints; text boxes can't have line returns & text areas can! You'll have to use a text area and handle "hard" returns either on the client using JS or the server using whatever language you're on. Just remember any client side parsing should be complimented on the server side if data integrity is important.